# When to use pointer as parameter in function c++?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I'm a beginner in C++. I think I understand pointers and references, and started using them as parameters to functions.

Is there ever a time for a function parameter to be a pointer, when a reference is less work and is easier to understand?

For example, using a pointer as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add_one(int *x);

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    add_one(&a);
    cout << a << "\n";
    add_one(&a);
    cout << a << "\n";
    add_one(&a);
    cout << a << "\n";
}

void add_one(int *x) {
    *x += 1;
}
```

versus a reference as parameter:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void add_one(int &x);

int main() {
    int a = 0;
    add_one(a);
    cout << a << "\n";
    add_one(a);
    cout << a << "\n";
    add_one(a);
    cout << a << "\n";
}

void add_one(int &x) {
    x += 1;
}
```

Comment: In `c++` we use pass by reference. In `c` which did not have pass by reference we had to pass by pointer to modify the passed in value.

Comment: when `nullptr` is a valid parameter you can use a pointer

Comment: there are are cases, like if you had an 'optional' parameter, like i dont know a function that can do some extra logging of debug information if you pass a logger but wont if its not present so you would have `if (logger) logger->AddMessage("xyz");`, arrays whose size you dont know at compile time (see [fstream's write](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/write)), and probably other cases i cant think of right now

Comment: One use case in c++ for pass by pointer that was used is an optional bool that is an out parameter. For example: [https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toInt) in modern c++ there are other ways this can be accomplished.

Comment: A lot of pointer use cases in C++ exist because they also existed in C, and we've been lugging that legacy for a while. In general, you should avoid using pointers if alternatives are available.

Comment: New programmers may look at `add_one(&a);` and say the extra `&` makes it more complicated and more difficult to understand, while experienced programmers may say the `&` carries information and makes it easier to understand.  There's a reason that C# (for example) requires the `ref` or `out` keyword at the caller of a method and not only in the method definition, even though the definition is everything that the compiler needs.

Comment: Note there's a competing philosophy that says outputs should be returned, not copied to buffers passed in parameters.  This is substantially easier with support for "structured binding", a feature in modern C++ which eliminates the disadvantages previously faced by packing multiple outputs into return values.

Comment: Use a pointer as a parameter to a function when it could be **null**, and when it is a *non-owning* pointer.